# How to create custom tag helpers for razor?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core-mvc, tag-helpers

I'm trying to create a custom tag helper in MVC 6 but can't make it work.

Here is my demo tag helper class defined in the web app project.

```cs
namespace Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.TagHelpers
{
    [TargetElement("demo", Attributes = CustomAttributeName)]
    public class DemoTagHelper : TagHelper
    {
        private const string CustomAttributeName = "asp-custom";

        [HtmlAttributeName(CustomAttributeName)]
        public string Custom { get; set; }

        public string Value { get; set; }


        public override void Process(TagHelperContext context, TagHelperOutput output)
        {
            output.TagName = "div";
            output.Attributes["foo"] = "bar";
        }
    }
}
```

This is how I use it in my views:

```cshtml
<demo asp-custom="hello world!">
    Please work this time :)
</demo>
```

I tried many things. Removed `TargetElement` attribute or changed the namespace. Nothing changes...
The result is still same.

By the way my **Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.TagHelpers** version is **6.0.0-beta4**.

Maybe I have to register my tag helper somewhere? I looked into MVC source codes and they haven't referenced their own tag helpers anywhere. So I think there is no registration needed.

Where is the problem here?

Comment: See http://docs.asp.net/projects/mvc/en/latest/views/tag-helpers/authoring.html on how to create custom tag helpers.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can enable the `TagHelper` processing for the custom tags by adding an `addTagHelper` directive to the `_ViewImports.cshtml` file found in the Views directory:

```
@addTagHelper "*, YourMvcAssembly"
```

**Update**

@yilmaz also needed to add a reference to `Microsoft.AspNet.Tooling.Razor` as detailed below in the comments.

Comment: Now I managed to make it work. I needed to add two things and this was one of them. And the other one was a reference to **Microsoft.AspNet.Tooling.Razor** assembly. So maybe you can add this one too to your answer to make it more complete for the future uses.

Comment: @Yilmaz Nice one, I've added that to the answer too. Thanks. :)

Answer (score 2):

This is what I have for a custom tag helper currently and it works. I changed it to target a demo element. Try it out:

```
namespace TestingTagHelpers.TagHelpers
{
    using Microsoft.AspNet.Razor.Runtime.TagHelpers;
    using System;

    /// <summary>
    /// <see cref="ITagHelper"/> implementation targeting &lt;demo&gt; elements.
    /// </summary>
    //[TargetElement("demo")]
    public class DemoTagHelper : TagHelper
    {
        public override void Process(TagHelperContext context, TagHelperOutput output)
        {
            var childContent = context.GetChildContentAsync().Result;
            string demoContent = childContent.GetContent();
            string demo = context.AllAttributes["asp-custom"].ToString();

            output.TagName = "div";
            output.Attributes.Clear();
            output.Attributes["data-custom"] = demo;
            output.Content.SetContent(demoContent);
        }
    }
}
```